# Configuration of AutoMapper with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

In ASP.NET Core, AutoMapper is now configured like this (in  `Startup.ConfigureServices`):

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { 
    cfg.AddProfile(new MyConfig());
});
services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(sp => config.CreateMapper());
```

Why not the following:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddProfile(new MyConfig());
});
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

Is there a difference? Something to do with lazy loading maybe?

Comment: First one creates the instance on first request, second during bootup

Comment: @Tseng Please add as answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First one creates the instance on first request, second during bootup.